# Firebase waiting to load database data before promise fires

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, onload

Can someone please explain how to use promises with Firebase with my code below:

```
        var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var data=null;

            var ref = db.ref("/");
            ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
                data = snapshot.val();

            });

            data.onload = function() {
                console.log(data+" onload");

                if (data!=null) {
                    resolve('Success!');
                }
                else {
                    reject('Failure!');
                    console.log('failed');
                }

            }

        });

        p.then(function() { 
            /* do something with the result */
            console.log(data+" done");
        }).catch(function() {
            /* error :( */
            console.log("error");
        });
```

I'm wanting to wait until I 'hear back' from `data = snapshot.val();` before I call my next function. What is the correct way to go about this? I'm clearly not understanding promises. I'm trying to follow [this](https://davidwalsh.name/promises) tutorial.

Comment: Looking at your code, it's firebase you need to brush up on! Ignoring the promise code, the rest of the code looks completely wrong

Comment: I mean, your `var p` can simply be `var p = db.ref("/").once("value");` - because `once` returns a promise! ... then it's `p.then(function(result) { ... do something with the result ...})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are built into firebase directly.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();

ref.once('value')
  .then(function (result) {
    // This only happens after the data has been returned
    console.log(result.val());
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    // This is where errors land
    console.log('Error', err.code);
  });
```

Version 3 of firebase has you covered so you do not need to create container promises.  :)